# Create an event that is connected to the change of a variable value?

Tags: variables, events, boolean, anylogic, event-based-components

I have issues with the following problem in AnyLogic:

I would like to create an event that is connected to a changing value of another variable. That variable can wheter be 1 or -1. At any moment it changes from -1 to 1, that event shall be triggered, but only once per occasion. Does anyone have a solution for this?

I already thought about implementing an boolean that checks that change, but I wouldn't know how.

Answer (score 2):

You need to approach this the other way around.

You are trying to "monitor" the variable and wait for a change of it.

Instead, you should only allow 1 way to change that variable and add any additional model changes that come from it.

In OOP, you do it by:

1. setting your variable `myVariable` to access level `private`
2. adding a `public` function `setMyVariable(int newValue)` next to it
3. in the function, you have the code `myVariable = newValue;` AND any other code you want to be triggered whenever `newValue==1` or `newValue==-1`
4. change your model such that `myVariable` is only ever changed via the function `setMyVariable(...)`

Comment: A *much* worse solution would be to have a cyclic event that constantly checks if `myVariable==1` and do something if it happens. *MUCH* worse :)